# Default text won't show if ttk widget name or StringVar is not global

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, tkinter-entry

I thought it would be good to get my Tkinter widget names out of the global namespace so I put them all in a def main() and called main(). But when I did this, the `ttk.Entry` stopped displaying the default text. But it works if I change it to a `tk.Entry`.

This can be done with a button and `entry.get()` as shown but in my larger application I do need the stringvar so as far as I know I need `tk.StringVar()`'s `set()` method.

I tried using a `textvariable` in a `config()` method on the entry name and it did the same thing.

I added a `ttk.Combobox` since it's part `ttk.Entry` and it has the same problem.

QUESTION: Is there anything wrong with the two globals declared for `StringVar()`s in Example 3? Why or why not? I don't know when to draw the line on globals. All the yammering against them makes me never want to use a single one, ever, but maybe that's impossible in procedural coding?

EXAMPLE 1: default text displays in entry with `tk.Entry` or `ttk.Entry`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+500+300')

def get_txt():
    lab2.config(text=ent.get())

x = tk.StringVar()
x.set("default entry text")

y = tk.StringVar()
y.set("default combo option")

ent = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=x) # either tk or ttk can be used here and default text will show
lab = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=x)
lab2 = ttk.Label(root)
buttn = ttk.Button(root, text='GET TEXT', command=get_txt)
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['dog', 'cat', 'goldfish'], textvariable=y)
lab3 = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=y)


ent.grid()
lab.grid()
lab2.grid()
buttn.grid()
combo.grid()
lab3.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

EXAMPLE 2: default text displays in entry with `tk.Entry`, not `ttk.Entry`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    def get_txt():
        lab2.config(text=ent.get())

    x = tk.StringVar()
    x.set("default entry text")

    y = tk.StringVar()
    y.set("default combo option")

    ent = tk.Entry(root) # this is where the ttk has to be changed to tk for the default text to show up
    ent.config(textvariable=x)
    lab = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=x)
    lab2 = ttk.Label(root)
    buttn = ttk.Button(root, text='GET TEXT', command=get_txt)
    combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['dog', 'cat', 'goldfish'], textvariable=y) # there's no tk.Combobox
    lab3 = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=y)

    ent.grid()
    lab.grid()
    lab2.grid()
    buttn.grid()
    combo.grid()
    lab3.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
main()
root.mainloop()
```

EXAMPLE 3: global reference to `StringVar()`--back to globals??

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    def get_txt():
        lab2.config(text=ent.get())

    # x = tk.StringVar()
    x.set("default entry text")

    # y = tk.StringVar()
    y.set("default combo option")

    ent = ttk.Entry(root) # this is where the ttk has to be changed to tk for the default text to show up
    ent.config(textvariable=x)
    lab = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=x)
    lab2 = ttk.Label(root)
    buttn = ttk.Button(root, text='GET TEXT', command=get_txt)
    combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['dog', 'cat', 'goldfish'], textvariable=y) # there's no tk.Combobox
    lab3 = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=y)

    ent.grid()
    lab.grid()
    lab2.grid()
    buttn.grid()
    combo.grid()
    lab3.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
x = tk.StringVar()
y = tk.StringVar()
main()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen references to this problem. Must be a bug in tkinter.ttk - looks like variable x goes out of scope, although why it only happens with ttk.Entry and ttk.Label, and not with their tk counterparts is beyond me.

In any case, the following is a neater solution and works fine:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class main(tk.Tk):

    def get_txt(self):
        self.lab2.config(text=self.ent.get())

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = tk.StringVar()
        self.x.set("default entry text")

        self.y = tk.StringVar()
        self.y.set("default combo option")

        self.ent = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.x)
        lab = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.x)
        self.lab2 = ttk.Label(self)
        buttn = ttk.Button(self, text='GET TEXT', command=self.get_txt)
        combo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=['dog', 'cat', 'goldfish'], textvariable=self.y)
        lab3 = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.y)

        self.ent.grid()
        lab.grid()
        self.lab2.grid()
        buttn.grid()
        combo.grid()
        lab3.grid()

root = main()
root.mainloop()
```